# Django : Previous and next week button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a timesheet application. I want to display timesheet on a weekly basis, which I am able to do.
I have create previous and next week button.

what approach should I use, so that when someone clicks on previous week, it shows timsheet for previous week and same for next week.

note - I have a timesheet table that contains one entry per day for time entry.

**models.py --**

```
class TimeRecords(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = 'Employee ID')
    ts_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False,verbose_name = 'Time Sheet Date')
    ts_effort = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=8,verbose_name = 'Hours worked')
    ts_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name = 'Time Description')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Time Records'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Time Records'
        unique_together = (("emp_id", "ts_date"),)
        ordering = ["-emp_id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ts_desc
```

**forms.py ---**

```
class CreateTimeSheetForm(forms.ModelForm):     

    emp_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=123) 

    class Meta:
        model = TimeRecords
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
        "ts_desc": "Task Description"
            }
        widgets = {
        'ts_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True}),
        }
```

**views.py ---**

```
def dateEnds():
    date=datetime.date.today()
    year, week, dow = date.isocalendar()
    if dow == 1:
        start_date = date
    else:
        start_date = date - timedelta(dow)
    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    return start_date ,end_date

def daterange():
    start_date, end_date=dateEnds()
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

def timeEntryList(request):
    start_date, end_date=dateEnds()
    time_records=TimeRecords.objects.filter(emp_id=emp_id,ts_date__range= 
    (start_date, end_date))
    context = {'time_records': time_records}
    return render(request, 'timesheets/list.html', context)
```

**list.html --**

```
<tr> <th > Date</th> <th> Efforts</th> <th> Description</th> <th> Action</th> </tr>

                {% for time_record in time_records %} 
                <tr>
                    <td >{{ time_record.ts_date|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ time_record.ts_effort }}</td>
                    <td>{{ time_record.ts_desc }}</td>
                    <td ><a href="../{{time_record.id}}/edit">Edit</a> <a href="../{{time_record.id}}/delete/">Delete</a></td>                  
                </tr> 
                {% endfor  %}
              </table>   
            <a href="/timesheets/view" ><button type="button" class="btn" >Previous Week</button></a>
```

Comment: Your `dateEnds()` function is just for using `today`? Where can you input your `start_date`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this problem.

In `models.py`,

```
class TimeRecord(models.Model):
    ts_date = models.DateTimeField()

    # Other fields

    def get_week(self):
        return self.ts_date.isocalendar()[1]
```

In the `views.py` I would use list comprehensions to get time records for previous week and next week.

```
from django.utils import timezone

def my_view(request):

    context = dict()

    time_records = TimeRecord.objects.all()
    current_week = timezone.now().isocalendar()[1]
    current_records = [time_record for time_record in time_records if time_record.get_week() == current_week]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        week = request.POST['week']

        if week == 'next-week':
            current_records = [time_record for time_record in time_records if
                               time_record.get_week() == current_week + 1]

        if week == 'last-week':
            current_records = [time_record for time_record in time_records if
                               time_record.get_week() == current_week - 1]

    context['current_records'] = current_records

    return render(request, 'my.html', context)
```

Finally in the templates I would used hidden form inputs for next week and previous week.

```
<div>
    {% for record in current_records %}
        <p># {{ forloop.counter }} {{ record.ts_date }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="week" value="next-week">
        <button type="submit">next week</button>
    </form>

      <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="week" value="last-week">
        <button type="submit">last week</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. Getting more hopeful now.. Though Please help on one issue --

I am getting below error -

File "C:\Users\SaurabhMaheshwari\Desktop\SESS\sess_dev\timesheets\views.py", line 53, in timeEntryList
    current_records = [time_record for time_record in time_records if time_record.get_week() == current_week]
...
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Also, where is get_week() function defined

Comment: The error is in `__str__`  method in your TimeRecord model. It returns a DateTime instance instead of a string. You can use `strftime` to convert DateTime  to string.

Comment: def __str__(self):
        return self.ts_desc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

like this ?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: same erro.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

Comment: I will make an edit on views.py , Cool? Also the get_week() method is defined inside the TimeRecord Model.

Comment: anything is fine, which gets my requirement fulfilled :)

Comment: I changed `views.py` according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: Can you delete  `__str__` entirely, I feel like this is where the problem is. If it works you can add it back later. Also, don't forget to save  your changes and restart the server.

Comment: so sorry for pestering you a lot of times..
did all what you said..still same error.

Comment: Attach an Image with the that showing the whole traceback. That's the only way I can understand where the problem is coming from?